# display series of products from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

i am working on one project, where i need to display products from mysql table using php.

My design is like that, 5 products display in one row and so on.

So if there is 7 products in table, it should be 2 rows.

```
first row 5 products
second row 2 products
```

I am using `<UL>` and `<LI>` to display product and row like

```
<UL>
<li>first</li>
<li>2nd</li>
<li>3rd</li>
<li>4th</li>
<li>5th</li>
</ul>

<UL>
<li>6th</li>
<li>7th</li>
</ul>
```

I am wondering how to use foreach loop to get code like above.

If i use `forloop with 5 increment` i am unable to get products from table and display their name.

Thanks

Comment: -1 because using a counter and an if statement should be so obvious. have you put any thought at all into this? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($yourResultSet as $index=>$data) {
    echo '<li>' . YourOutput . '</li>';        

    if ($index % 5 == 0) {
        echo "</ul><ul>";
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: +1, as it doesn't use db calls in the view layer. Minor tweak - if the number of rows is exactly divisible by 5, an unnecessary unordered list will be created. Still, fixing that can be the OP's task `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): /* Used to loop through a resultset*/ ?>
    echo "<li>".$row['data'].</li>";
<?php 
    $i++; // Increment by one every loop
    if($i == 5){ // We've hit the fifth iteration
        echo '</ul><ul>'; // Close the UL and open a new UL
        $i = 0; // Set $i back to 0 and continue looping
    }
    endwhile;
?>
</ul>
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

your best way of achieving this is to have your `<li>`'s have a specific width so that five of them fit in the parent container and that the following two or however many you have will drop to the next line.

```
<style>
#container {
    width: 350px;
    background: red;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
} 
#list li
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background:blue;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <ul id="list">
    <?php 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<li>' . $row['data'] . '</li>'; 
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You'll need to play with the sizes a bit but everything should work, and it you have 11 products this should do 2 rows of 5 and a third row of 1 product.